# Retrieving ContentProvider entry from a file path

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, mediastore

I have a very specific need of retrieving Artist and Track from a song coming from a few different use cases. It is usually possible for me to query the MediaStore from a mp3 uri (scheme: `content://`) pretty easily, but I sometimes receive a file path instead (scheme: `file://`).
I stumbled upon this post on StackOverflow :
[Get MediaStore content Uri from File path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045965/get-mediastore-content-uri-from-file-path)

Unfortunately, it looks like it doesn't work for me. I'm definitely doing something wrong somewhere but I can't tell where.
Here is the code that I use, and the filePath that I give it is verified prior to its execution.

Here's the piece of code :

```
    private void getTrackFromFilePath(String filePath) {

    String[] filePathColumn = {
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, //
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST
    };

    Uri musicUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Logger.e(TAG, musicUri.toString() + " filePath: " + filePath);

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(musicUri, filePathColumn, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " LIKE ?", new String[] {
        filePath
    }, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor);

    cursor.close();
}
```

And here is the logcat associated :

```
01-21 12:14:40.345: E/MusicScannerActivity(13513): content://media/external/audio/media filePath: file:///mnt/sdcard/Music/07%20Olly%20Murs%20Feat%20Flo%20Rida%20-%20Troublemaker.mp3
01-21 12:14:40.350: I/System.out(13513): >>>>> Dumping cursor android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@41e03748
01-21 12:14:40.350: I/System.out(13513): <<<<<
```

I tried playing around a little bit with the columns I'm requesting but with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those wondering, I found the answer to my question myself, and several things prevented this thing to work.
The first one is that the spaces represented in the file path that I was getting were encoded like this: `%20`, but were just spaces in the `MediaStore` so no match could be done.
The second is that the file that I was getting had the `file://` scheme, which the `MediaStore` doesn't include.

I basically solved the issue by doing this :

```
    filePath = filePath.replace("file://", "");
    filePath = filePath.replace("%20", " ");
```